# Need help figuring out while my function isn't working (PYTHON)

Tags: python, function

I am new to Python coding and I'm trying to write a short text-based adventure game. I'm trying to write a function that takes the current health and subtracts the monsters value given by a random call. Here's what I have.

```
import random

monster = 0
health = 100

def monEnc(monster,health):
    monster = random.randint(0,21)
    health = health - monster
    print(health)
    return

monEnc()
```

When I try and run the code, monEnc() does nothing and I'm kind of lost.

Comment: At least in the code you've provided above, you're missing indentation for the body of the function. What errors are you getting when you try to run this?

Comment: Please, present your code with proper indentation

Comment: I've edited to provide proper indentation. 

Sublime tells me:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python Code\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    monEnc()
TypeError: monEnc() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
[Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: monEnc(monster=VALUE_NOT_GIVEN, health=VALUE_NOT_GIVEN) give some values to this function.

Answer (score 5):

Your function "monEnc" takes 2 parameters, while you pass it none. If you don't want it to return anything, don't include return at all. You probably want something like:

```
import random

def monEnc(monster,health):
    health = health - monster
    print(health)
    return health

monEnc(0, 100)
```

or

```
import random

def monEnc(health):
    monster = random.randint(0,21)
    health = health - monster
    print(health)
    return health

monEnc(100)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. Now when I continue to apply the function, the health left is always calculated from 100 instead of the remaining value. Any pointers?

Comment: think about it - why would the health value change permanently if you're not assigning a new `health` variable after each time `monEnc` is called?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Right now, your function returns the difference of the health variable (in this case 100), and the randomly generated monster variable.

Comment: n1c9, how come 'health = health - monster' doesn't apply the new value of the math to the health variable?

Comment: Heretohelp, I'd like the value of health to be retained after taking "damage" from the monster. Say randint returns 15 and now health = 85, the next time I call monEnc I want health to calculated from 85 instead of 100 again.

Comment: It does apply the new value, but when you `return` that new value, you're not assigning it to any variable. The new value gets applied, and the new health gets returned, but unless you assign a variable to that function call (i.e. `new_health = monEnc(100)` the `return` value just vanishes. it appears what you want is something like `new_health = monEnc(100)`, then `new_health = monEnc(new_health)`, so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I understand what you're saying but I'm having some trouble applying it. I'll fiddle it with it some more before coming back!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you were not passing the monster and health parameters to your function which caused the error. The monster variable is created inside your function so does not need to be passed as a parameter.

```
import random

health = 100

def monenc(health_points):
    monster = random.randint(0,21)
    health = health_points - monster

print(monenc(health))
print(monenc(health))
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted as well. Now when I continue to apply the function, the health left is always calculated from 100 instead of the remaining value. Any pointers?

Comment: Ah I see your issue, keeping the health value separate as above should work, that way the health variable will be updated with the new value each time the function runs.